# JUnit in Ant build script attempting and failing to delete .svn directory

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm following an example from Pragmatic Project Automation. I'm running on Windows 7 and pulling the project from a local Subversion repo. When I run `ant` in the project's base directory, I get the following error `[junit] couldn't delete .svn`. Here's the full output of the command:

```
Buildfile: S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build.xml

prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build\prod
    [mkdir] Created dir: S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build\test

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build\prod

compile-tests:
    [javac] Compiling 7 source files to S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build\test

test:
    [junit] Testsuite: com.pragprog.dms.DocumentTest
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testsuite: com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testTitleSearch(com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest): Caused an ERROR
    [junit] couldn't delete .svn
    [junit] java.io.IOException: couldn't delete .svn
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.create(FSDirectory.java:166)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.<init>(FSDirectory.java:151)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.getDirectory(FSDirectory.java:132)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:160)
    [junit]     at com.pragprog.dms.Indexer.index(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest.setUp(Unknown Source)
    [junit] 
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testContentSearch(com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest):   Caused an ERROR
    [junit] couldn't delete .svn
    [junit] java.io.IOException: couldn't delete .svn
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.create(FSDirectory.java:166)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.<init>(FSDirectory.java:151)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.getDirectory(FSDirectory.java:132)
    [junit]     at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:160)
    [junit]     at com.pragprog.dms.Indexer.index(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest.setUp(Unknown Source)
    [junit] 
    [junit] 

BUILD FAILED
S:\CruiseControl\builds\dms\checkout\dms\build.xml:33: Test com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest failed

Total time: 0 seconds
```

and the build.xml file:

```
<project name="dms" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <property name="build.prod.dir" location="${build.dir}/prod" />
    <property name="build.test.dir" location="${build.dir}/test" />
    <property name="doc.dir" location="doc" />
    <property name="index.dir" location="index" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="test.dir" location="test" />
    <property name="vendor.lib.dir" location="vendor/lib" />
    <path id="project.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build.prod.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${vendor.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${build.prod.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.test.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="prepare">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.prod.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="compile-tests" depends="compile">
        <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${build.test.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="test" depends="compile-tests">
        <junit haltonfailure="true">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${build.test.dir}" includes="**/*Test.class" />
            </batchtest>
            <sysproperty key="doc.dir" value="${doc.dir}" />
            <sysproperty key="index.dir" value="${index.dir}" />
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Why is JUnit attempting to delete a .svn directory? Which one is it even trying to delete? Why is it failing to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like test case `testTitleSearch` in `com.pragprog.dms.SearchTest` is failing. The same then happens with `testContentSearch`. They are perhaps trying to clean house before starting.  I'm guessing you inadvertently put the test case's scratch directory under version control when cloning it locally.

Comment: I used to use `-N [--non-recursive]` a lot, but I see `--depth` is now preferred.

Comment: Ahh, turns out it was using the index/ folder in the base directory of the project as a scratch folder. The build script executes just fine now. I ended up using Process Explorer to isolate which folder was the problematic one. That doesn't seem to be a very efficient way of doing things though. Is there a better way to troubleshoot this, like say... is it possible to get JUnit to spit out the full path?

Comment: I not sure about `JUnit`, but older versions of `ant` may need to [`enableTestListenerEvents`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).